# How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL with JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this delete script:

```
DELETE auth, cust
FROM customer cust 
JOIN authentication_token auth ON auth.customer_id = cust.id
WHERE cust.email = 'my@email.com';
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_table`.`authentication_token`, CONSTRAINT `authentication_token_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`))
```

I've tried to change the order of the DELETE statement (cust, auth), and I've tried to change the order of the join, but still the same error.

Is this possible, or will I have to temporary disable constraints?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `passwordSalt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `county` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registeredOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `authentication_token` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `authentication_token_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`)
)
```

Comment: can you share parent and child table structure ?

Comment: @Ravi updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `authentication_token` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `authentication_token_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

And then just run this SQL:

```
DELETE FROM cust WHERE cust.email = 'my@email.com';
```

When you delete the records from `cust`, the relevant records in `authentication_token` will be deleted automatically.

Comment: That's great! I didn't know about automatic cascaded deletes. That's a great solution, much better than what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot delete or update a parent row

It means, you can't update/delete parent table, since, reference still exist in some other child table(s).

If you wanted to delete from both table, then best solution would be altering your table to add

```
ON CASCADE DELETE
```

It will ensure that all the references rows gets deleted.

```
CONSTRAINT `authentication_token_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON CASCADE DELETE
```

Comment: I'm not specifying columns, I'm specifying tables.

Comment: @user7862512 `DELETE auth, cust` are they table ?

Comment: yep. They're tables which I've aliased in the from and join statement.